# Sample graph dataset for testing algorithms

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

I hope I'm addressing the right community. For a project for my students, I need to find some weighted graphs (oriented or not) to benchmark their algorithms (shortest paths, flows...).

There are a few samples on the companion site of the ALGS4 course from R. Sedgewick ([Shortest Paths](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/)), but I would like some more datas, encoded in this simplest way (or easily convertible).

Maybe someone here is aware of some samples and could point me to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question would be better suited for cs.SE. Anyway, for classical tasks like shortest paths and flows I would recommend using some already available problem collection in some online judge, for example https://cses.fi/problemset/.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know CSES. Can't seem to find their datasets...

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/6454/1106, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47342/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/128968/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @Laakeri, may I make a request?  In the future if you suggest another site, can you remind folks not to cross-post?  You can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. : I posted on several sites because eash time, I was directed to another one... I know this is bad behaviour, I apologize.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, if you post on the wrong site, you can delete the copy on that site before posting elsewhere, and all is good!

Answer (score 1):

The [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/) appears to include a few weighted graphs. Unfortunately the road networks are apparently unweighted - I'm not sure if shortest-paths is motivated on any of the weighted graphs there.